# How to Highlight Selected 3D Geometry in Pyglet/OpenGL with Lighing On?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I'm trying to do mouse picking in pyglet, and I found it hard to highlight selection, especially with glLight on, since they OVERRIDE object colors.

Here's the general structure for my code. I'm trying to draw a grid that you can select and move grid points around (there will be structures generating from the points, hence the 3d lighting). I know the if statement for glMaterialfv is ridiculous, but that's what I tried. They used to be in the draw() function.

So what should I do to highlight selection in a 3d lighted scene? Should I assign different specular lighting? How should I achieve that? Or should I constantly add and delete the selected point into a different batch (is that wasteful) with a different draw function? What are your general approaches?

(As an experiment I tried to add lighting to this [mousepicking example](https://sites.google.com/site/swinesmallpygletexamples/mouse-picking), and it stopped working once the light is on.)

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
#grid class
def __init__(self,rows,cols,spacingX,spacingZ):
    self.rows, self.cols = rows, cols
    #......some other code generating the grid#
    self.hilightIndex = None
    self.Lines = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    self.Dots = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    self.pointList = {}
    #grid points#
    for row in range(self.rows+1):
        for col in range(self.cols+1):
            point=#something
            self.pointList[(row,col)]=point
            if (row,col)==self.hilightIndex:    #selected
                glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, vec(1, 1, 1, 1))
                glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, vec(1, 1, 1, 1))
            else:
                glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, vec(0, 0, 0, 1))
                glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, vec(0, 0, 0, 1))

            glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 50)
            self.Dots.add(1,GL_POINTS, None,('v3f',point))
    #grid lines#
    for row in range(self.rows):
        for col in range(self.cols):
            uL=self.pointList[(row,col)] 
            #......*4 points of the grid
            self.Lines.add(2,GL_LINES, None,('v3f/stream',uL+uR))
            #......*4 sides
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, vec(0, 0, 0, 1.0))
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, vec(0, 0, 0, 1))
            glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 50)



def draw(self):
    #......some line stipple and point size code
    self.Lines.draw()
    self.Dots.draw()
```